# What's the appropriate way to return a reference to the value from a generic associated function?

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

Imagine a tiny map that stores 3 values, the first two for known keys. I'd like to implement an iterator for this map, but I'm running into lifetime issues. What's the appropriate way to return a reference to the value from a generic associated function (`K::zero()` in the example below)? 
FYI, I own the trait, so I tried changing it to the new [RFC195](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md) associated `const`, which didn't help.

I've boiled down my problem to the following code:

```
extern crate num;

use num::*;

pub struct TinyMap<K: Num, V> {
    v0: Option<V>, // value for K::zero()
    v1: Option<V>, // value for K::one()
    k2: K,         // arbitrary K
    v2: Option<V>, // value for k2
}

pub struct Iter<'a, K: 'a + Num, V: 'a> {
    k0: K,
    v0: &'a Option<V>,
    v1: &'a Option<V>,
    k2: &'a K,
    v2: &'a Option<V>,
}

impl<K: Num, V> TinyMap<K, V> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<K, V> {
        Iter {
            k0: K::zero(),
            v0: &self.v0,
            v1: &self.v1,
            k2: &self.k2,
            v2: &self.v2,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, K: 'a + Num, V: 'a> Iterator for Iter<'a, K, V> {
    type Item = (&'a K, &'a V);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(&'a K, &'a V)> {
        if (*self.v0).is_some() {
            // code removed that remembers we did this once.
            return Some((&self.k0, ((*self.v0).as_ref()).unwrap()));
        }
        // if (*self.v1).is_some() {
        //     code removed that remembers we did this once.
        //     return Some((&K::one(), &((*self.v1).unwrap())));
        // }
        None
    }
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:38:26
   |
38 |             return Some((&self.k0, ((*self.v0).as_ref()).unwrap()));
   |                          ^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 35:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:35:5
   |
35 | /     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(&'a K, &'a V)> {
36 | |         if (*self.v0).is_some() {
37 | |             // code removed that remembers we did this once.
38 | |             return Some((&self.k0, ((*self.v0).as_ref()).unwrap()));
...  |
44 | |         None
45 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:38:26
   |
38 |             return Some((&self.k0, ((*self.v0).as_ref()).unwrap()));
   |                          ^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 32:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:32:6
   |
32 | impl<'a, K: 'a + Num, V: 'a> Iterator for Iter<'a, K, V> {
   |      ^^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected std::option::Option<(&'a K, &'a V)>
              found std::option::Option<(&K, &V)>
```

Comment: Could you please include the full error message in your question?  It's the most important bit of information when trying to find the cause of an error.

Comment: You won't be able to unwrap `self.v0`, since you only borrowed it. The error message is probably caused by the fact that the first element of your pair has a lifetime tied to the borrow of`Iter` passed in as `self`, while the return value requires lifetime `'a`, which is tied to the borrow of the underlying `TinyMap` stored in the iterator. An iterator can't return items that are tied to the lifetime of `self`, since this would require [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md), which are not yet supported by Rust.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Emphasis on **minimal**. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: For example, [this continues to reproduce the error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ae9d6ce438a5dd384b0ca9f9e6d88864&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) and you could probably get even smaller with minimal effort.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the minimal example. Sorry, I couldn't get it down that far (my code is actually much larger). (I know this is just an excuse, but I thought context mattered here, because I have no other place I can put K::zero()).

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I found this [link] (https://medium.com/@jordan_98525/reference-iterators-in-rust-5603a51b5192) that explains why iterators can't return references to values they hold. Even if I get rid of the reference to self.k, I have a lifetime error with the value part. So I guess there are two questions here: how do I return a reference to K::zero(), and what's with the lifetime error on the value?

Comment: I fixed the problem with the value. The correct expression is (*self.v0).as_ref().unwrap(), so the only remaining issue is K::zero(). If I put that in my TinyMap it won't be tiny anymore... I'll go with that for now.

Comment: The easiest way to fix the problem with `K::zero()` is to store it in `TinyMap` as well, even if it is  redundant.  If `K` wasn't a generic type, the problem would be trivial to solve, since you could introduce static variables for 0 and 1 and return references to the static variables, solving all lifetime issues.  If `K` needs to be generic, and you really can't store all the keys in `TinyMap`, you may be able to build something using `lazy_static` and `typemap`, but it's probably not going to be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus appears to be that as of this time (Rust 1.29), the only sensible way is to put `K::zero()` inside `TinyMap`. Thanks to @SvenMarnach for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that with the `Iterator` trait, because of the lifetime of the self reference (which is elided away in your code, but can be explicitly written like this):

```
type Item = (&'a K, &'a V);
fn next<'s>(&'s mut self) -> Self::Item;
```

Since `'s` doesn't appear in the function's return value (and can't appear in there, because `Self::Item` can't use type parameters of the function), the output is not allowed to hold a reference to any of the iterator's member variables.

That's the mechanics of the mistake, now here's the *why* part:

Consider a function that does include a reference to a member of self, with all the lifetimes set up correctly:

```
struct SomeMember;
struct SomeObject {
    some_member: SomeMember,
}
impl SomeObject {
    fn some_function<'s>(&'s mut self) -> &'s SomeMember {
        &self.some_member
    }
}
```

The same way you're trying to return `&self.k`, but without any other things going on, and with the lifetimes fixed so that it's allowed. However, if I then try to do this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut some_object = SomeObject{some_member: SomeMember};
    let _item_1 = some_object.some_function();
    let _item_2 = some_object.some_function();
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `some_object` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:15:23
   |
14 |         let _item_1 = some_object.some_function();
   |                       ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
15 |         let _item_2 = some_object.some_function();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
16 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

The second call wasn't allowed, because it borrows `some_object` twice, mutably, a classic Rust no-no! But if I had tried to implement an iterator with an Item type that borrowed the iterator itself, then `Iterator::collect()` would be impossible, because it tries to pull more than one item out at once!

So, no, an iterator can't return an item that borrows its contents. That's an explicit, and intentional, part of the trait contract for iterators.

Comment: Thanks, I get the "next() can't reference iterator contents" now. Is there a way to return a reference to K::zero() without putting it in TinyMap (as it would no longer be tiny)?

Comment: I don't agree with the "why" part.  This is _not_ an intentional part of the contract for iterators.  It's just not possible in current Rust to parametrize associated types with a lifetime, so the `Item` type simply can't be tied to the lifetime of `self`.  This is actually the motivating example in the [generic associated types RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md).